# Failed to install vertica client 9.1.1 windows server 2012

Tags: vertica

The Vertica Client Drivers 9.1.1 finishes with the message "installation failed".
No additional data about the error, no logs and no messages in the windows system event log.
I'm using Windows server 2012
How to understand the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Windows Server 2012.

First you need to manually install and enable the .NET Framework 3.5. Then you will be able to install the client drivers.

You can follow this link for instructions on how to install the .NET Framework 3.5 (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/50892.windows-server-2012-r2-install-net-framework-3-5-feature-offlineonline.aspx). Follow the "Install .NET 3.5 Framework Features on Windows Server 2012 R2 (Online)" instructions.